# Hash function for strings

Tags: java, strings, hash-map, hashcode

Implementation of a hash function in java, haven't got round to dealing with collisions yet.
I tried to use good code, refactored, descriptive variable names, nice syntax.

My code must be efficient and extensible.

Would be interested to know how you guys would improve.
Three classes:

1. TestHash - main method is here, hash is initialised and data
   inserted and read
2. HashTable -object were the hash table is held
3. HashEntry - each entry in the array is a 'HashEntry' object

**HashTable**

```
import java.io.*;

public class HashTable {
    // number of indexes in hash table
    private final static int TABLE_SIZE = 100;
    // initialise array of HashEntry (table)
    HashEntry[] table;

    // constructor, create array, assign all values to null
    HashTable() {
        // create array of HashEntry, predefined size
        table = new HashEntry[TABLE_SIZE];
        // assign all values to null
        for (int i = 0; i < TABLE_SIZE; i++) {
            table[i] = null;
        }
    }

    // from key, find the correct index, load the HashEntry object and return the value
    public String getValue(String key) {
        int index = this.getKeyIndex(key);
        HashEntry chosen_entry = table[index];
        String chosen_entry_value = chosen_entry.getValue(key);
        return chosen_entry_value;
    }

    // creates a new HashEntry object, inserts that into the table array at the correct index
    // determined by getKeyIndex(key)
    public void insert(String key, String value) {
        int index = this.getKeyIndex(key);
        HashEntry keyValuePair;
        keyValuePair = new HashEntry(key, value);
        table[index] = keyValuePair;
        return;
    }

    // ** PRIVATE FUNCTIONS ** //
    // get index from key
    private Integer getKeyIndex(String key) {
        int hash = 7;
        for (int i = 0; i < key.length(); i++) {
            hash = (hash*31 + key.charAt(i))%100;
        }
        return hash;
    }
}
```

**HashEntry**

```
public class HashEntry {
    private String key;
    private String value;

    HashEntry(String key, String value) {
        this.key = key;
        this.value = value;
    }

    public String getKey() {
        return this.key;
    }

    public String getValue(String key) {
        // use string key to move down linked list in case of collision
        // haven't implemented this yet
        return this.value;
    }
}
```

**TestHash**

```
public class TestHash {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        HashTable tableHash = new HashTable();
        tableHash.insert("david", "england");
        tableHash.insert("joe", "united states");
        tableHash.insert("maria", "china");
        System.out.println(tableHash.getValue("joe"));
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you willing to look at any other answers? I was working on one, but you've already accepted the current one. If you still want a review, please tell me.

Comment: @user2296177 feel free to share your inputs too, it may help others looking at this question! :)

Comment: If your answer is significantly better than what is currently given I would be happy to accept yours.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Very nifty-looking code right there. However, you should declare `table` as `private final`. Also, you don't need to initialize each array component of `table` to `null`, Java already does this for you. What comes to `insert`, you could write simply

```
table[index] = new HashEntry(key, value);
```

omitting the `return` statement. Point is to write only necessary statements. In `getValue`, you might want to check whether `table[index]` is `null`, since if that is the case, your implementation will throw `NullPointerException`.

Comment: Nice answer, clear and understandable.
What do you think of the getKeyIndex method in the HashTable class, could this be improved (I was a bit unsure myself)?

Comment: I am not an expert on hashing, yet your implementation seems sufficient. However, I would consider using/reusing `String.hashCode`: it seems to do pretty much the same you do, but the point is that each `String` computes its `hashCode` only once and caches it (subsequent calls to `hashCode` will just return the cached hash value), so if you would use just `String.hashCode`  instead of `getKeyIndex`, you would have better performance.

Comment: The caching sounds like good advice, so how would I add a 'hashCode' variable to the specific String object I am working with? I would google this, but I am not sure what search terms to use.

Comment: I can't parse your question what comes to "add a `hashCode` variable". Create a `String`. Call `hashCode` on it; it will compute the hash code, cache it, and finally return it. Call `hashCode` one more time, and your `String` will return the cached value without actually computing it. This is all because strings are immutable (do not change state).

Comment: Sorry, I massively miss-read what you was saying. Caching sounds like a good idea. Although correct me if I am wrong, the caching process itself would likely rely on an implementation of a hash map.